# From where is this poem?

Tags: poetry

Hi can someone please tell me from where this poem is and what it's called?

> The thick dank mists come stealing down,
>   And press me on every side.
>   With never a voice to cheer me on,
>   And never a hand to guide

I once wrote it down and now I would love to find a recording of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the process of writing or publishing, but about an existing work. It might belong on Literature.SE.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Chris*! Please note that this site is dedicated to the craft of writing. There are many sites on the StackExchange network though, for example [Literature.SE], which focuses on existing literature. Every site has a [tour] and [help] that show you what the focus of each one is. Please have a look at them. Have fun on the site!

Comment: @Galastel A little tip: You can use [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/352819) like `[Literature.SE]` to write a link to the site (it will display as [Literature.SE]). It's two more characters, but it makes it a lot easier for people to follow where you are poiting them.

Comment: When I am looking for a poem or short story I enclose what I know in inverted commas and it usually comes up e.g. "The thick mists come stealing down". The author's name is just about always part of the page.

Comment: Can this be migrated to [Literature.SE]? While the question itself isn't great (given it could be resolved by a basic internet search), I found it useful to learn about this poet and his work, and as a beta site it might welcome the extra post ;-)

Comment: [Let me Google that for you.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=The+thick+dank+mists+come+stealing+down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Shakespeare, it's Seumas MacManus and is called "In Dark Hour". It's in a compilation called *Ballads of a Country Boy*:

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Y2cNAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22ballads+of+a+country+boy%22++Seumas+MacManus+%22in+dark+hour%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwprLx--vcAhUBAcAKHTojChwQ6AEIKTAA

It's in here too:

[https://www.amazon.com/Dreams-Images-Anthology-Catholic-Classic/dp/1330758307/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1534230246&sr=8-2&keywords=anthology+of+catholic+poets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1330758307)

The easiest way to find something like this is to take part of the verse, enclose it in double speech marks and put it into Google. It will then search for the exact line rather than the individual words.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The poem is called "In Dark Hour", and it is by Seumas MacManus, not Shakespeare. It is published within his book, Ballads of a Country-boy. There is a copy of it on [this webpage](http://catholicpoemsandstories.blogspot.com/2018/03/in-dark-hour.html).